# Filter out dataframe based on values being within the 90th percentile

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have this dataframe

```
d = {'fruit': ['apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'orange'], 'names': ['bob', 'bob', 'bob', 'joe']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Now I want to go through each column and filter out the low percentiles keeping only values that are contained in the 90th percentile.

Thus since `apple` and `bob` are each within their associated 90th percentiles I would have this dataframe

```
d = {'fruit': ['apple', 'apple', 'apple'], 'names': ['bob', 'bob', 'bob']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps:

1. Calculate 90th percentile and keep them in a dictionary:

```
perc_dic = df.apply(lambda x : np.percentile(x.value_counts().tolist(), 90) , axis= 0).to_dict()

perc_dic 
{'fruit': 2.8, 'names': 2.8}
```

2.Calculate value counts of each value:

```
value_dic = df.apply(lambda x : x.value_counts() , axis= 0).to_dict()

value_dic
{'fruit': {'apple': 3.0, 'bob': nan, 'joe': nan, 'orange': 1.0},
 'names': {'apple': nan, 'bob': 3.0, 'joe': 1.0, 'orange': nan}}
```

3. Compare value counts and percentile:

```
df_result =  df.apply(lambda row : row  if value_dic['fruit'][row['fruit']] >= perc_dic['fruit']  and
                                           value_dic['names'][row['names']] >= perc_dic['names']
                                          else np.nan , axis= 1)

df_result.dropna()
    fruit   names
0   apple   bob
1   apple   bob
2   apple   bob
```

Note:  There are some nan values in value_dic but it won't hurt the performance.